# Integrating Google Sheets API in Java Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, google-sheets-api

HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THIS?

I am following [this google doc.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java)

Currently, my `SheetsQuickstart.java` file runs with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport.<init>(Lcom/google/api/client/http/javanet/ConnectionFactory;Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport$Builder.build(NetHttpTransport.java:317)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.java:55)
    at SheetsQuickstart.main(SheetsQuickstart.java:63)
```

Where should I keep my `credentials.json` file?

Are there any more steps in servlets to overcome this? Any Doc or a simple demo project(or anything related) will help

Comment: Please share the code here, specifically the minimal code required to reproduce the error. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The code was fine. The issue was of ```credentials.json``` and some other minor settings in google console. Thanks for your response though :) @Aerials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Question basically was:

> Where to keep the credentials.json files if you are working with Java struts or servlets?

The mentioned link (Google Doc) describes the config for android (I think).
After experimenting with it, I found that you can keep the `credentials.json` in your `src` folder itself.

Also, the steps to use GAPI are:

1. Create a project in Google Console.
2. Config your OAuth Screen.
3. Create your OAuth Credentials.
4. Download `credentials.json` and place it your src folder.
   That should be it. Hope it helps somebody.